# Rails Join Table Add Multiple records in form with item_ids: []

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

Hi I have a rails application with two models Delivery and Item, these models are joined by a join table DeliveryItem

```
class Delivery < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :delivery_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :delivery_items

  enum status: [ :unapproved, :approved, :scheduled ]
end

 class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :delivery_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :deliveries, through: :delivery_items

  enum status: [:unscheduled, :scheduled, :delivered]

end

class DeliveryItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :delivery
  belongs_to :item
end
```

In my form to add items to a delivery I want to be able to add multiple like so

```
<%= form_for @delivery_item, html: {class: 'form-inline'} do |form| %>
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= form.collection_select :delivery_id, @project.deliveries.all, :id, :date, placeholder: 'Add to Delivery', class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= form.collection_check_boxes :item_ids, location.items.unscheduled.all, :id, :assembly_name, multiple: true %>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
            
                <%= form.submit class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block' %>
            
              </div>
            <% end %>
```

I am getting an error undefined method `item_ids' for #DeliveryItem:0x00007fd98d322440

the controllers are as follows

```
class Projects::DeliveriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_delivery, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :reset_item_status]
  before_action :reset_item_status, only: [:destroy]
  
  def show
    @delivery = Delivery.find(params[:id])
    @delivery_items = @delivery.items.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "some_name",
              template: "projects/deliveries/show.pdf.erb",
              layout: "pdf.html",
              margin: { top: 35, bottom: 35 }
      end
    end
  end
  # GET /deliveries/new
  def new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @delivery = Delivery.new
  end

  # GET /deliveries/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /deliveries
  # POST /deliveries.json
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @delivery = Delivery.new(delivery_params)
    @delivery.project_id = @project.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @delivery.save
        format.html { redirect_to @delivery.project, notice: 'Delivery was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @delivery.project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @delivery.project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /deliveries/1
  # PATCH/PUT /deliveries/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @delivery.update(delivery_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @delivery.project, notice: 'Delivery was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @delivery.project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @delivery.project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /deliveries/1
  # DELETE /deliveries/1.json
  def destroy
    @delivery = Delivery.find(params[:id])
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    title = @delivery.date
    if @delivery.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "One \'#{title}' was successfully destroyed."
      redirect_to @project 
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Error Yo"
      render :show
    end
  end
  
  def send_delivery_to_project_admin
    @delivery = Delivery.find(params[:delivery_id])
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    if @project.project_users.project_administrator.present?
      @project_administrator = @project.project_users.project_administrator
      DeliveryMailer.delivery_ready_to_schedule_email(@delivery, @project_administrator).deliver_now
      redirect_to approval_confirmation_path, notice: 'Mail was successfully sent.'
    else
      redirect_to @project, :flash => { error: 'Email not sent, no Project Administrator present' }
    end
  end

  def send_delivery_approval_request_to_project_manager
    @delivery = Delivery.find(params[:delivery_id])
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    if @project.project_users.project_manager.present?
      @project_manager = @project.project_users.project_manager
      DeliveryMailer.delivery_requires_approval_email(@delivery, @project_manager).deliver
      redirect_to @project, notice: 'Mail was successfully sent.'
    else
      redirect_to @project, :flash => { error: 'Email not sent, no Project Manager present' }
    end
  end

  def approval
    @delivery = Delivery.find(params[:delivery_id])
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @delivery.approved!
    redirect_to project_delivery_send_delivery_to_project_admin_path, notice: 'Delivery was approved.'
  end

  def scheduled
    @delivery = Delivery.find(params[:delivery_id])
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @delivery.scheduled!
    redirect_to delivery_confirmation_path, notice: 'Delivery was scheduled.'
  end

  def reset_item_status
    @delivery.items.update_all(status: 0)
  end

  private
  def set_delivery
    @delivery = Delivery.find(params[:id])
  end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def delivery_params
      params.require(:delivery).permit(:date, :project_id, :search)
    end
end

class Projects::ItemsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /items/new
  def new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def index
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @items = @project.items.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @items.to_csv }
    end
  end
  # GET /items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /items
  # POST /items.json
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    @item.project_id = @project.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item.project, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item.project }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @item.project, error: 'Item had an issue' }
        puts @item.errors.full_messages
        format.json { render json: @item.project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /items/1.json
  def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @item.project, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @item.project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @item.project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1
  # DELETE /items/1.json
  def destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    if @item.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "One \'#{@item.part_number.name}' was successfully destroyed."
      redirect_to @project 
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Error Yo"
      render :show
    end
  end

  def import
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @project.items.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to project_path(@project), notice: "Sucessfully Imported Items!"
   end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:project_id, :search, :part_number_id, :assembly_id, :location_id)
    end
end

class DeliveryItemsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_delivery_item, only: [:destroy]
 before_action :set_items, only: [:new, :edit]
  # GET /delivery_items/new
  def new
    @delivery_item = DeliveryItem.new
  end

  # GET /delivery_items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /delivery_items
  # POST /delivery_items.json
  def create
    @delivery_item = DeliveryItem.new(delivery_item_params)
    @items = 
    respond_to do |format|
      if @delivery_item.save
        @delivery_item.item.status = 1
        @delivery_item.item.save!
        format.html { redirect_to @delivery_item.item.project, notice: 'Item Added to Delivery' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @delivery_item.item.project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @delivery_item.item.project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /delivery_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /delivery_items/1.json


  # DELETE /delivery_items/1
  # DELETE /delivery_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @delivery_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      @delivery_item.item.status = 0
      @delivery_item.item.save!
      format.html { redirect_to @delivery_item.item.project, notice: 'Delivery item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Comment: It could possibly be bc your form is for @delivery_item which belong to an item. It's your Delivery model that has the has many relationship and therefore the item_ids

Comment: Interesting... But it has many through, or has many delivery items... i thought this would be quite a simple use case of a join table... I might just move the delivery to have many items and the item belongs to the delivery with optional true

Comment: Right but the form record argument you have there is @delivery_item. You have defined the relationships in there to belong to a delivery and an item. As such there is not item_ids available on the @delivery_item. If you're trying to assign a list of item_ids to a delivery I suggest you change the form argument to `@delivery` instead of @delivery_item

Comment: when i do that I get undefined method `deliveries_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fd98c9ef940>:0x00007fd98ca24ed8>
Did you mean?  delivery_items_path
               delivery_item_path

Comment: I don't know what your routes look like, I don't know what your structure looks like. Im simply trying to answer the part about why item_ids doesn't work when called on a delivery item